# generating pop up on another page when form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have 2 pages in jsp. 1 is doctor.jsp and the other is patient.jsp. Both pages are open in 2 different pc and have different views. what i want to do is that when patient form is submitted the patient.jsp is refreshed but data of form move to doctor page and a pop-up of div is generated in doctor.jsp. but the patient view remains as it is and just a pop-up is generated in doctor.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

For pushing information to a page using jquery check out the [Atmosphere framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/jQuery.atmosphere.js-API). You'll need both server and client side code to handle the transactions, and Atmosphere can make it a lot easier. I haven't used it in regular jsp but perhaps [this article](http://www.ncolomer.net/2012/03/cometwebsocket-introducing-the-atmosphere-framework/) is a good starting point for you.

Comment: i have got the answer. This can be done by refreshing the page again and again after some time. So when new entry in database is generated so you can update your popup.